# How to create a new layout for an Android project (using Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, adt

I think this is a fairly straightforward question but I have not been able to find an answer after some searching. I am new to Android development. I am using Eclipse and have ADT installed.

I just wanted to know if the IDE has a feature that will allow me to easily add a new layout file to my project.

At the moment I am manually adding a file to the project and calling it something like mynewlayout.xml and then manually copying the xml from the default layout (added to new Android projects). I would like to find out if it is possible to create a new layout through the IDE like you would create a new activity (by selecting AndroidManifest.xml and choosing the Application tab).

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to file - new - other - Android - android XML Layout

Comment: Thanks a lot, put an end to my frustrating hunt for the right menu :).

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on the layout.
2. Then New
3. Then click on the android xml file.
4. Name of file like rossman.xml
5. Click finish